# Converting complex text file into json nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I have .dal file for example user.dal and in this dal file I am reading all the content using fs library. But I need to convert this into json but text file can have multiple children params.

```
dal getUserDetails {
    stream: { type: unary },
    request: {
        type: object,
        params: {
            email: { type: string, required: true},
            name: { type: object,
                params: {
                    firstName: { type: string, required: true}
                }
            }
        }
    },
    response: {
        type: object,
        params: {
            email: { type: string, required: true},
            name: { type: string, required: false}
        }
    }
}
```

```
function getProtoMessageParams(functionName) {
        let fileName = 'user';
        let content = fs.readFileSync(process.cwd() + "/" + 'src/dals/'+fileName+'.dal').toString()
        let protoParams:any = content.split(functionName)[1].split('//- RR')[0]
        protoParams = protoParams.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '').split(' ');
        protoParams.forEach((ele:any, index: number) => {
            ele = ele.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "");
            ele = ele.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
            ele = ele.trim()
            if (ele && (!ele.includes('{'))) {
                if(!ele.includes('}')) {
                    if(ele.includes(':')) {
                        protoParams[index] = '"'+ele.split(':')[0]+'":'
                    } else {
                        protoParams[index] = ele.includes(',') ? '"'+ele.split(',')[0]+'",': '"'+ele+'"'
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        protoParams = protoParams.join(' ');
        return JSON.parse(protoParams)
}
```

I have tried this function and it is working but when i give space in any parameter then it gives error

like this firstName: -> firstName   :

Comment: No idea what a DAL file is, but if it's anything approaching a complex grammar, write a parser.

Comment: dal is just extension, you can consider it as .txt

Comment: Is the top code an example of the DAL file? Where does `//- RR` come from?

Comment: Where does "when i give space in any parameter" happen? In the DAL file? What is example of "giv[ing] space in any parameter"? Exactly what error do you get?

Comment: In general parsing any relatively complex grammar simplistically will lead to tears. Since this appears very close to JS I'd probably repurpose a real parser or sketch a quick one using any of several parser generators. Or if it's something real see if one already exists.